# Minimal google geocoder not returning any result

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

**Preface:** *I have contacted google and read the documentation. When this is finished it will display the map on the next page and have autosuggest on the first - I will not be violating the terms and conditions this way, so please dont start a flame war*

I have set about trying to create my own minimal geocoder which geocodes without showing a map on the current page. I have found that there is no example code online for doing this! I am new to jquery but this is the best I could come up with. However, low and behold it doesn't work.

I am sure I have done something stupid, so I would appreciate it if someone could let me know if they spot any obvious reasons why this wouldn't work. I have never made a javascript before.

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/9/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function getLatLng() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div>
            <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
            <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
            <input id="lat" type="textbox" value="lat">
            <input id="lng" type="textbox" value="lng">
           </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: Watch out! You're loading the **experimental** version with the v=3.exp parameter. This version is unstable and your code can stop working at any time. Avoid using this version on a production site, if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well first 2 things I can see are that the `onclick` of the button is calling `codeAddress()`, but you have not declared that function - you can change that to `getLatLng()` and it should work then. Plus the `<body onload` is calling `initialize()` which is also not declared. While that should not prevent the geocoder from firing you should probably fix it.